# Git continue from a commit id

Tags: git, git-checkout

I try to learn git. I make some mistakes in my master and only branch. I checkout to a previous commit, not the last one. I want to continue from that point. What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-a-previous-git-commit .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have checked out to a previous commit, use the checkout command to create a new branch

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

This will create a new branch from where you are right now!!

Comment: And to make that my master I should merge newbranch master. Is that correct?

Comment: Ah! If u wish to destroy the wrong changes, I would suggest, you go ahead with the way suggested by the @Tony Barnes in comment. But if you wish to merge it with the master both the wrong and new changes will be seen in it. So that is a no-no